# facebook login issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I want to use facebook login to login on my website(C#.net).
I follow steps and it seems very easy.
But I stuck on authenticatio, can some one help me

This is my sample code

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId: '236948576362087', cookie: true,
        status: true, xfbml: true
    });
</script>
    <fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

It says, i need to supply applicationId, I just create one application and get its applicationId, but its gives me error..........

An error occurred with myapp. Please try later

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to register you websites domain on you facebook app's settings page.
Without doing this facebook won't authenticate against your site.
You need to go to Basic Settings and under the 'Select how your app integrates with Facebook' you need to enter you need to tick the 'Website' option and enter your websites domain.

Comment: it does not say anything like this, if it domain needs to supply where it should be on facebook app? where it should be     is it app domain field?????

Comment: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and click on edit settings for your app and then follow the instructions above. Make sure you save afterwards.

Comment: @Amit - If the domain you have registered against your app is the same as the site you're authenticating from then this should work.

Comment: Hey i already done so, its not working, How can i do in local developement environment? does it take localhost:port?   I have tried one of my live URL as well,its also not working

Comment: Yes, you must be right, but the thing I am facing is, the applicationId you can see in sample code is live, in application's website -> site URL i have supplied http://localhost:50559/ which is current port on which application runs, but still not working. any idea what i am doing wrong???